# R Custom Color Scale for Plotting

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps

I am attempting to create a custom scale that will better display the data I have. For the first plot, the data was relatively uniform, falling in between 0 and 3. However, for my second dataset, the majority of the data is less than 100, and approximately 90% of the data is under 1000. (plots at bottom)

The column with the values I am trying to plot is named 'data1', and the values are whole numbers ranging from 0-10000.

I tried applying the code on https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/178597/how-to-create-a-continuous-scale-with-distinct-custom-color-and-value-breaks-wit by inserting

```
map.df$brks <- cut(map.df$data1, 
                 breaks=c(0, 1, 10, 25, 100, 250, 1000, 10000), 
                 labels=c("0", "1 - 10", "11 - 25", "26 - 100", 
                          "101 - 250", "251 - 1000", "1001 - 10000"))
```

where the commented line is and replacing the fill argument with brks in the ggplot function call, but I get the following error: **Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale**.

```
stateNames <- c("alabama", "alabama", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", 
                "colorado", "connecticut", "florida", "georgia")
countyNames <- c("autauga", "blount", "apache", "bradley", "orange", 
                 "boulder", "new haven", "flagler", "turner")
dataCol <- c(0, 5, 15, 50, 150, 1000, 5000, 249, 30)

library(ggplot2)
map.county <- map_data('county')
counties   <- unique(map.county[,5:6])
data_map <- merge(counties, data.frame(region=stateNames, 
                                     subregion=countyNames, 
                                     data1= dataCol),
                  by=c("region","subregion"), all.x=T, all.y=F
)

data_map$data1[which(is.na(data_map$data1))] <- fillValue
for(i in 1:length(data_map$data1)) {
  if(is.na(data_map$data1[i])) {
    data_map$data1[i] <- 0
  }
}
library(data.table)
map.county <- data.table(map_data('county'))
setkey(map.county,region,subregion)
data_map <- data.table(data_map)
setkey(data_map,region,subregion)
map.df <- map.county[data_map]

############################################################# 

ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=data1)) + 
  scale_fill_gradientn("",colours=brewer.pal(9,"YlOrRd"))+
  geom_polygon(colour = borderColor, size = 0.001) +
  coord_map()  +
  expand_limits(x = map.county$long, y = map.county$lat) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  labs(x = "", y = "") +
  labs(fill=dataName)  +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", panel.background = element_blank())
```

Does anyone have advice on how I can create a custom scale? Thanks in advance!

[image: Previous Use of Code]

[image: New Application with Different Data]

Comment: Can you simplify your question and give an example data set we can use, and clarify what you mean by 'custom colour scale'. What's wrong with the one it gives you?

Comment: I apologize for being unclear. When I say "custom color scale", I meant being able to change the scale such that the colors do not change at a constant rate. If you see above, there are evenly spaced tick marks for every 2000 units. I would like to be able to replace those numbers with my own values, such as "0, 1, 10, 25, 100, 250, 1000, 10000" as shown in the first line of code above.

Comment: I have updated the question with a small sample dataset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. Explanations in annotated code below:

```
# add include.lowest = TRUE, otherwise the 0 values will become NAs
map.df$brks <- cut(map.df$data1, 
                   breaks = c(0, 1, 10, 25, 100, 250, 1000, 10000), 
                   labels = c("0", "1 - 10", "11 - 25", "26 - 100", 
                            "101 - 250", "251 - 1000", "1001 - 10000"),
                   include.lowest = TRUE)

# use scale_fill_brewer rather than scale_fill_gradientn; it expects
# a categorical variable (e.g. brks) while scale_fill_gradientn expects
# a continuous variable (e.g. data1).
# also, I suggest placing the legend at the side, as a vertical stack of 
# boxes, which resembles a color bar.
# theme_void can be used to remove all backgrounds, axis labels, etc.
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=brks)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour = "grey", size = 0.001) +
  coord_map()  +
  expand_limits(x = map.county$long, y = map.county$lat) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlOrRd") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image: map]