# Keep in legend all breaks in ggplot for maps

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, legend

I am working with maps, and I am struggling with keeping in legend all keys for breaks even when no cases fall in those breaks.

I am using some code from other question, edited to display my issue. Old question is here: [R Custom Color Scale for Plotting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602153/r-custom-color-scale-for-plotting)

In this example no state|county fall in the break **"1001 - 10000"** but I need to keep that key in legend. Code is below:

[image: map with missing break in legend]

```
stateNames <- c("alabama", "alabama", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", 
                "colorado", "connecticut", "florida", "georgia")
countyNames <- c("autauga", "blount", "apache", "bradley", "orange", 
                 "boulder", "new haven", "flagler", "turner")
dataCol <- c(0, 5, 15, 50, 150, 1000, 500, 249, 30)

map.county <- map_data('county')
counties   <- unique(map.county[,5:6])
data_map <- merge(counties, data.frame(region=stateNames, 
                                       subregion=countyNames, 
                                       data1= dataCol),
                  by=c("region","subregion"), all.x=T, all.y=F
)

data_map$data1[which(is.na(data_map$data1))] <- 0


map.county <- data.table(map_data('county'))
setkey(map.county,region,subregion)
data_map <- data.table(data_map)
setkey(data_map,region,subregion)
map.df <- map.county[data_map]

map.df$brks <- cut(map.df$data1, 
                   breaks = c(0, 1, 10, 25, 100, 250, 1000, 10000), 
                   labels = c("0", "1 - 10", "11 - 25", "26 - 100", 
                              "101 - 250", "251 - 1000", "1001 - 10000"),
                   include.lowest = TRUE)

ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=brks)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour = "grey", size = 0.001) +
  coord_map()  +
  expand_limits(x = map.county$long, y = map.county$lat) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlOrRd") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply add the argument `drop = FALSE` in `scale_fill_brewer`:

```r
ggplot(map.df, aes(x=long, y=lat, group=group, fill=brks)) + 
  geom_polygon(colour = "grey", size = 0.1) +
  coord_map()  +
  expand_limits(x = map.county$long, y = map.county$lat) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "YlOrRd", drop = FALSE) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "right")
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Saved twice in a day. Thanks again. I never had to use ** drop = FALSE ** before, so I also learned something new today. Glad you found this question.